# multiple select box filter to show hide div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a page filter to show hide div based upon combine dropdown values, for that some page had two select boxes and some had 3 select boxes combination and after selecting each value from select boxes a particular div should show or hide. I got some luck to reach at point but couldn't get further please help.

```
$(".submit-button-filter").click(function () {
      $(function(){

        var places = $("#places").val();
        var zones = $("#zones").val();
        var stories = $("#stories").val();
        var year = $("#year").val();
        var month = $("#month").val();
        var filters= [places, zones, stories, year, month];
        console.log(filters);

        if(year == 'Year' && month == 'Month'){
           alert("Select Filer value");
        }
        else if(year == 'Year' || month == 'Month'){
           alert("Select combine Filer value");
        }
        else{
          $('.row-sort').hide();

        }

      });
     });
```

[Here is fiddle for my code](https://jsfiddle.net/mohit7189/p4ow1h7f/1/)

Answer (score 0):

you are fetching the dropdown selected value but first option in the select tag do not have value attribute so try below code

```
var year = $("#year :selected").text();
var month = $("#month :selected").text();
```

Comment: $("#places"), $("#zones"), $("#stories").,$("#year"), $("#month") 

if any one of these element is also Select tag then try as above

Answer (score 0):

You just need to iterate through each div with class `row-sort` and check if the selected options are available as classes in those divs. If so, just show them.

```
$(".submit-button-filter").click(function () {
      $('.row-sort').hide(); // hide all divs

        var year = $("#year").val();
        var month = $("#month").val();
        var filters= [year, month];

        if(year == 'Year' && month == 'Month'){
           alert("Select Filer value");
        }
        else if(year == 'Year' || month == 'Month'){
           alert("Select combine Filer value");
        }
        else
        {
          $('.row-sort').each(function()
          {
             if($(this).hasClasses(filters))
                $(this).show();
          });        
        }
     });

// user defined function to check for multiple classes using hasClass
$.fn.extend({
         hasClasses: function (selectors) {
        var self = this;
        for (var i in selectors) {
            if ($(self).hasClass(selectors[i])) 
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Working example : https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/p4ow1h7f/5/

Comment: very thanks Dino for your quick help and now I was able to create the combination filter from your code but facing a new problem that if I  wanted to show an alert if the filter value doesn't matches, but alert is coming even for matched value  here is the updated fiddle for it     https://jsfiddle.net/mohit7189/p4ow1h7f/12/

Comment: I could not replicate a scenario where I got the alert message even when valid values were selected. Could you tell me whats values did you choose from the dropdown which triggers the irrelevant alert ?

Comment: actually it was an alert message which i am pushing in a span no matter what the conditions are the mesaage is still coming in every case